# error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: visual-c++, cppunit

error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#include <cppunit/Portability.h>
#include <cppunit/portability/Stream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


CPPUNIT_NS_BEGIN


/*! \brief Methods for converting values to strings. Replaces CPPUNIT_NS::StringTools::toString
 */
namespace StringHelper
{

// work around to handle C++11 enum class correctly. We need an own conversion to std::string
// as there is no implicit coversion to int for enum class.

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, std::string>::type toString(const T& x)
{
    OStringStream ost;
    ost << x;

    return ost.str();
}
```

Im refering cppunit file in my vc++ project for unit test execution.
while building the application, getting the above error.

Comment: What does your code that triggers the issue look like?

Comment: @RetiredNinja , ost << x; here its throwing the error

Comment: Are you saying that a completely empty project, just `int main() {}` that includes cppunit is failing to compile? I suspect rather that some of your code is using that template in some way. The error message should tell you the actual type of `T`.

Comment: What's `OStringStream`? Is it somehow related to `std::ostringstream`?